# Change MySql DataSet query at runtime in Visual C# 2015

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2015, dataset, rdlc

In a Visual C# 2015 desktop project, I created a DataSet that retrieves data from a MySql table. I also created a Report and I was able to add three fields of the table in it. Then I created a form, added a ReportViewer and selected the aforementioned Report to it.

The report looks good and loads the data as expected. But, I would like to be able to programmatically modify the sql query of the DataSet TableAdapter that feeds the report (or any other object that would achieve the same). I see in its properties the SelectCommand -> CommandText property (which is the one I would like to change at runtime). Visual C# doesn't let me; so I try to do the same with the query "Fill, GetData()" CommandText property, but I can't either.

In the form load event I have this (the default without modifications):

```
this.productosTableAdapter.Fill(this.dSProductos.productos);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

"productosTableAdapter" is my TableAdapter and "dsProductos.productos" is the DataTable. Of course I tried things like I mentioned above but to no avail (like: `this.productosTableAdapter.Adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select field1, field2 from...`").

What could I do to change the sql query of that dataset that feeds my report at runtime? (Note that I'm using MySQL, not SQL Server).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I was able to change the SQL of a table adapter query at runtime.
Even if creating multiple queries by table adapter was a workaround, was not what I wanted.

I will share my solution so it can help anyone with my same use case.

After researching a lot of articles, the first thing I took a look at was the dataset designer generated code and search the declaration of the table adapter so I could extend it and add a method that can modify the sql of the query. I found the following:

```
namespace pos.source.datasets.ProductosTableAdapters {

    /// <summary>
    ///Represents the connection and commands used to retrieve and save data.
    ///</summary>
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(true)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DataObjectAttribute(true)]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.DesignerAttribute("Microsoft.VSDesigner.DataSource.Design.TableAdapterDesigner, Microsoft.VSDesigner" +
        ", Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a")]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.Design.HelpKeywordAttribute("vs.data.TableAdapter")]
    public partial class productosTableAdapter : global::System.ComponentModel.Component {
        private global::MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter _adapter;
        private global::MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection _connection;
        private global::MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlTransaction _transaction;
        private global::MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand[] _commandCollection;
...
```

So, based on this, I added a new class in a separate file with the following contents (the same namespace and the same declaration of class):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace pos.source.datasets.ProductosTableAdapters
{
    public partial class productosTableAdapter : global::System.ComponentModel.Component
    {
        public void SetSQL(string theSQL)
        {
            this.CommandCollection[0].CommandText = theSQL;
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I modified the code of the button in the form in charge of loading the report:

```
sqlQuery = "select * from productos order by codigo";  // Basic sample where I just changed the "order by" clause which will be chosen dynamically on the form by the end user
this.productosTableAdapter.SetSQL(sqlQuery);
this.productosTableAdapter.Fill(this.dSProductos.productos);
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

So, this way, I could change the first table adapter query sql command text at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using a **typed** DataSet, which has a table that has a predefined list of columns.

Use a regular DataTable instead for the report.  I assume your reportViewer1 has a DataSource property that is predefined to your typed data set, so that's why I have the DataSource property addition on the viewer.

```
System.Data.DataTable tbl = new System.Data.DataTable();
this.productosTableAdapter.Fill(tbl);
this.reportViewer1.DataSource = tbl;
this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
```

Comment: Interesting. I will try this approach. Thanks!

Comment: We had some problems trying to do this programmatically. We ended up creating multiple queries in a single table adapter of a dataset (using parameters in some of them) and choosing one of them depending on the values on the form.